# Is there a modern equivalence of Asimov's book "The new intelligent man's guide to science"?

Tags: reference-request

I enjoyed Asimov's "The new intelligent man's guide to science" very much when I was a teenager. I noticed that he later published "Asimov's New Guide to Science", however that was also nearly 40 years ago. My question is, are there more recent books that are more or less equivalent (in term of range and depth) to Asimov's book?

Comment: You can see [Jim Al-Khalili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Al-Khalili)'s books, e.g. [The World According to Physics (2020)](https://books.google.it/books?id=8_-tDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)